# I want to retrieve an XML attribute value using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, nodes

I want to search an attribute value that exists in an XML file using XPath, for example to search in the nodes values you type "//ex1/ex2/ex3/text()" but what if i want to get the value of a parameter exists in a node,

let's consider a want to get **humidity** from the following XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
    <!-- api6.weather.ch1.yahoo.com Thu May 16 06:04:56 PST 2013 -->
     -<channel> 
 <language>en-us</language>
 <ttl>60</ttl> 
<yweather:atmosphere pressure="29.97" visibility="3.73" rising="0" humidity="73"/> <yweather:astronomy sunset="6:41 pm" sunrise="4:59 am"/>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Do you mean "attribute", instead of "argument" or "parameter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `//*/@humidity`. That would give you all `humidity` attribute nodes, everywhere in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You would use `//atmosphere/@humidity`. GO through this [XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) tutorial.

Comment: That won't work, since `<atmosphere>` is in the yweather namespace.

Comment: but when i use it like this i have no errors but also have no returned result

Comment: XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ttl/text()");

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.STRING);

System.out.println(result);

Comment: @BrassBlock: no error because it's syntactically correct, but no result because no element matches `//atmosphere`. There is an element that matches `//yweather:atmosphere`, but you have to declare the namespace prefix in order to use that form.

Comment: @LarsH dude. i just gave an example of how to retrieve the attribute values using xpath. I could have made sure that namespace etc everything works but it is unnecessary noise. as even //yweather:atmoshpere wouldn't work without declaring the prefix and let xpath engine aware of this.

Comment: i used the way that @LarsH said to me "//*/@humidity" and it works so well with me as i'm will always search a parameter that exists once in the file so i don't have to distinguish between different values of a same named parameters

Comment: @Pangea, in a subject where I'm a noob, anything that's suggested to me that doesn't work, and I can't figure out why (as the OP couldn't with your sugg), is a significant barrier. If your answer said "This may not actually be right for your document but it's the general syntax for retrieving attribute values", it would be less misleading. Since it uses element and attribute names specific to his XML, yet won't work with his XML, I would find it very confusing.